# makefile with multiple files and dependencies

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I know this makefile is very trivial, but i have been reading some tutorials and examples trying to learn it and apply. **Is there something wrong with what i have shown or should this be working with the includes that i showed?**

All of the files are located in the `CWD` where make is run.

---

Here is a list of my dependencies.

```
CT.c includes: studio.h, math.h, "CT.h", "TM.h"
CT.h includes: none
TM.c includes: "TM.h", stdio.h, math.h
TM.h includes: none
RP.c includes: "CT.h", math.h, fftw3.h, stdio.h, stdlib.h, "TM.h"
RP.h includes: fftw3.h
RF.c includes: "RF.h", stdlib.h, stdio.h
RF.h includes: none
DR.c includes: stdio.h, math.h, "DR.h"
main.c includes: "CT.h", "DR.h", "TM.h", "RP.h", "RF.h", stdio.h, math.h, time.h, stdlib.h, fftw3.h
```

---

Here is my makefile that is not working:

```
RFST: main.o CT.o TM.o RP.o RF.o DR.o
        gcc -L/home/me/projects/RFST/libs -o RFST main.o CT.o TM.o RP.o RF.o DR.o -lfftw3 -lasc -lmfhdf -ldf -lz -ljeg -lm
main.o: main.c CT.h TM.h RP.h RF.h DR.h
        gcc -I. -c main.c
CT.o: CT.c CT.h TM.h
        gcc -I. -c CT.c
TM.o: TM.c TM.h
        gcc -I. -c TM.c
RP.o: RP.c RP.h CT.h TM.h
        gcc -I. -c RP.c
RF.o: RF.c RF.h
        gcc -I. -c RF.c
DR.o: DR.c DR.h
        gcc -I. -c DR.c
```

---

When attempting to run the makefile it complains that things are not declared, but all those things are declared in the various header files that are included.

Example:

```
'vA' undeclared(first use in this function)
'Variables' undeclared(first use in this funcion)
```

`Variables vA[];` is in main.c.
`Variables` is a `struct` in `DR.h` and it is being included in main.c.

Comment: you error message is?

Comment: Why .h files in required list? Your .c file will not compile if header files are missing.

Comment: @gongzhitaao, added example error.

Comment: @dbasic, can you elaborate? I am not understanding your comment. "Why .h files in required list?"

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the makefile. Could you show us `main.c`?

Comment: This is not a makefile problem, but rather a code problem. The same errors would be given if you try to compile directly from the command line.

Comment: as @Beta suggested, I could not reproduce the error you got. try some simple dependence list to see if you got the same error.

Comment: I am looking at the code now. If i can not figure it out, i will post more information. Thanks in the mean time.

Comment: A couple of the header guards were miss-typed. Fixing those two header guards fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of the header guards were miss-typed. Fixing those two header guards fixed the issue.